# Decoding json object in javascript that is returned from ajax

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, json

I've prepared an array in php for ajax return with json_encode.  When returned through ajax, it is not behaving as I expected.

### ajax call and my attempt to interrogate results

```
$.ajax({

     url:"dbpaginate.php",
              type:"POST",
              data: {'environmentvars': tmp},
    cache: false,

    success: function(response){
        alert('Returned from ajax: ' + response);
        alert(response["actionfunction"]);
        $j.each(response, function (index,element) {
            alert(index);
            alert(element);


        });
});
```

### first alert message:

```
Returned from ajax: array(5) {
["actionfunction"]=>
string(8) "showData"
["sortparam"]=>
string(6) "ticker"
["sortorder"]=>
string(3) "ASC"
["page"]=>
int(1)
["htmlstring"]=>
string(0) ""
}
{"actionfunction":"showData","sortparam":"ticker","sortorder":"ASC","page":1,"htmlstring":"","htmltext":"<table id=\"summaryheader\"> [...lots of html...]<\/div>\n"}
```

### Second alert message

```
undefined
```

### Expected result

```
showData
```

How can I effectively port my json `response` into a javascript object environmentvars?  Thanks.

Comment: In case someone else is stumped by the same, I was using a var_dump() in php to write to a server-side log, which added the initial text at the top.  As I was new to ajax, I thought that the leading info in the first alert was part of a proper return.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to make the response valid JSON. It seems you have a `print_r` statement somewhere in your server side script, whose output gets included into the response. Remove that.

The response is always text, i.e. a string in JavaScript
. You can parse the JSON before processing the data futher ([Parse JSON in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4935632/218196)) or tell jQuery to parse it for you, by adding the `dataType: 'json'` option.

Answer (score 0):

You should specify a dataType parameter in such methods which is basically used to declare the type of data you are expecting from the server.

Here is an example:

```
$.ajax({
  type: "POST",
  url: <your-request-url>,
  data: <your-data>,
  success: function(){ ... },
  dataType: "json"
});
```

More details here: https://api.jquery.com/jquery.post/